# How do you set a property of an object in an array state in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

Let's say we want to keep the filters of a list in a state.

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState([])
```

And one sample of `filters` array could be:

```
[
    {
        "property": "Name",
        "value": "John",
        "operator": "eq"
    },
    {
        "property": "Age",
        "value": "18",
        "operator": "gt"
    },
    {
        "property": "IsMarried",
        "value": true,
        "operator": "eq"
    }
]
```

Now let's say I want to change `18` to `24`. This is my code. But it does not work:

```
const setFilter = (property, value, operator) => {
    var isAdded = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
        if (filters[i].property === property) {
            if (filters[i].operator && operator && filters[i].operator === operator) {
                const otherFilters = filters.filter(i => i.property !== property && i.operator !== operator)
                setFilters([...otherFilters, {
                    property,
                    operator,
                    value
                }])
                isAdded = true
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!isAdded) {
        setFilters(previousFilters => [...previousFilters, {
            property,
            operator,
            value
        }])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just map over `filters` state and change `value` or `operator` if the `property` matches as:

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-worker-vp1t28?file=/src/App.js)

```
  function setFilterValue(property, value, operator) {
    return filters.map((filter) => {
      return filter.property === property
        ? { property, value, operator }
        : filter;
    });
  }

  function changeFilterValue() {
    const value = setFilterValue("Age", "24", "gt");
    setFilters(value);
  }
```

Comment: But it only changes the state directly inside the state variable. It does not call React's `setFilters` set state function.

Comment: It is not changing state directly we are returning   new state (i.e array) and which is argument of `setFilters `. Answers updated